# Youtube Progress bar will not go away in fullscreen mode

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, youtube, fullscreen

Started a few months ago, having trouble getting full-screen progress bar to recede after a few seconds, but now no matter what I do I cannot get it to go away. I've tried clicking on the black portion and moving mouse off-screen, leaving the mouse pointer to different locations on the screen, etc. nothing works. I've cleared all my cash's, cleaned out my PC, defragged, I have done a system restore, etc. Any more ideas, or any news when Google will fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be because of some unwanted browser plugins/extensions or some adware (software designed for the purposes of advertisement) installed on your machine (like toolbar applications).

What I would suggest is, go to 'Uninstall a program' and look for such unwanted applications installed on your machine and remove them, then restart your browser.

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm 100% certain I have no adware on my system, I think it's something else.